# JSF 2 view scoped bean not updated when action is called second time

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I have a view scoped arrayList as bean. This is used to display the editable columns of dataTable. When the page is displayed initially and I try to update the table contents the update works fine, however when I try to update any column the second time the values which are changed do not reflect in the arrayList bean (verified in the action method using break point). The action method is also a managed bean with view scope.

```
 <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>financialListBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.util.ArrayList</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Below is the code for dataTable

```
        <h:form id="myform">
    <h:dataTable id="financialListBean1"
    value="#{financialListBean}" var="varfinancialListBean"
    styleClass="dataTableEx" headerClass="headerClass"
    footerClass="footerClass"
    rowClasses="rowClass1, rowClass2"
    columnClasses="columnClass1" border="0" cellpadding="2"
    cellspacing="0">
    <h:column id="columnEx17">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox styleClass="inputRowSelect"
    id="rowSelect3" 
    value="#{varfinancialListBean.rowSelected}"></h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    <f:facet name="header"></f:facet>
    </h:column>
    <h:column id="amount1column">
    <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText styleClass="outputText" value="Amount"
    id="amount1text"></h:outputText>
    </f:facet>
    <h:inputText styleClass="small8Input" id="amount1"
    value="#{varfinancialListBean.amount}" onkeypress="return only5DigitsEntry(this, event);" onkeyup="return checkRequiredFieldsForUpdateFinancialBtn(this.form, event);">
    </h:inputText>
    </h:column>
    <h:column id="type1column">
    <h:selectOneMenu styleClass="selectOneMenu" id="menu1" value="#{varfinancialListBean.type}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="M" itemValue="M" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Y" itemValue="Y" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Z" itemValue="Z" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="O" itemValue="O" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="S" itemValue="S" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText styleClass="outputText" value="Type"
    id="type1text"></h:outputText>
    </f:facet>
    </h:column>
    <h:column id="recDate1column">
    <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText styleClass="outputText"
    value="Recieve Date" id="recDate1text"></h:outputText>
    </f:facet>
    <h:inputText styleClass="outputText" id="recDate1"
    value="#{varfinancialListBean.recDate}" 
    onclick="getClock($(this).attr('id'))" > 
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MMM d, yyyy"/>
    </h:inputText>
    </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton type="submit"
    value="Update Financial Information"
    styleClass="commandExButton" id="updateFinancialBtn"
    action="#{pc_SocialServicesView.doFinancialUpdateBtnAction}">
    <f:param name="mrn" value="#{pc_SocialServicesView.mrn}" />
    </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
```

The action method:

```
public String doFinancialUpdateBtnAction() {

    System.out.println("I am at doFinancialUpdateBtnAction");


    try{
        if(mrn.length()==0){
            mrn=getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("mrn");
        }
             setFinancialListBean(dba.updateFinancialAsistance
      (getFinancialListBean(), mrn));
        setErrorMsgBean("Updated successfully ...");
        doInit(mrn);
    }catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("There is an exception at      doFinancialUpdateBtnAction");
        Log.out.error("Error in doFinancialUpdateBtnAction: "+e);
        setErrorMsgBean("No record was updated ...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: Is your action method entered the second time? If not, is there any error in client (javascript error)?

Comment: Yes, action method is called the second time I have put a break point to verify the bean contents. I do not see any javascript error. When I access the page for the first time, I can do the update. @MattHandy

Comment: Sometimes ViewScoped beans behave like RequestScoped beans. Can you debug to check whether your bean is recreated during/after submit?

Comment: I would assume that if the bean is recreated it would be null and not prepolate with values ? could you please let me know how to verify if it is recreated ? @MattHandy

Comment: Add a breakpoint in the constructor (if you don't have any, create one with a single command, maybe a print out).

Comment: no, its not created during/after submit. I am retrieving the bean using                                                                        financialListBean = (ArrayList) getManagedBean("financialListBean");                                                                protected Object getManagedBean( String mgdBeanName ) {
  String expression = "#{" + mgdBeanName + "}";
  return resolveExpression(expression);
 }                                                       @MattHandy

Comment: So please add relevant part of your bean code.

Comment: thank you for looking in to the code, I have updated the code with the action method in the bottom @MattHandy

Comment: That is a somewhat extraordinary design you have. Why is your ArrayList defined as bean and not as field of your `pc_SocialServicesView` bean?

Comment: The field would also serve the same purpose as that of the bean declaration. I will try to change and see if that helps @MattHandy

Comment: <managed-bean-class> -- The fully qualified class name of the application class used to instantiate a new
instance. This class must conform to JavaBeans design patterns -- in particular, it must have a public zero-args
constructor, and must have public property setters for any properties referenced with nested <managed-property>
elements -- or it must be a class that implements java.util.Map or java.util.List. @MattHandy

Comment: I tried with the field and I am able to update the list of beans. However the same code worked in JSF 1.2 with session scope. In JSF 2 when I used the list as a bean <managed-bean-class>java.util.ArrayList<managed-bean-class> the property of the bean contained in the list would be applied only for the first time when action is invoked. If I invoke the action again the changes I made in the list would not be applied (tried with all the scopes). This is little puzzling @MattHandy